# I cant access process env file from react components

Tags: reactjs

In my react app I set base_url in process env file. But I can't access it from components. Is I needed to install dotenv module or something?

`BASE_URL=http://localhost:5000/api`

I cant access .env from components

Comment: How are you trying to access it? React is a client-side library but the env file is server side, so you can't just access it directly.

Comment: Well, you haven't specified what kind of tool you used to bootstrap that React app. In case it's a create-react-app, then you have to add the `REACT_APP_` before every environment variable definition. Like so, `REACT_APP_BASE_URL=http://localhost:5000/api`. Again, the answer is different depending on your setup.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to access .env files in your react app you should use prefix
REACT_APP_ in front of your variable name.

write like this,

```
REACT_APP_BASE_URL= http://localhost:5000/api
```

Comment: The answer to the question is already available on stack overflow. It's better to research before asking questions to avoid repetition of questions.

Answer (score 0):

No, you don't need to install something else to access constants from file `.env`. Just replace it by `REACT_APP_BASE_URL`.

Remember to add prefix `REACT_APP_` in every constants you want to access from `.env`.